# $service not defined in Google Calendar API

Tags: php, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to use Google's Calendar API create (insert) a new event. I'm keeping it simple and using the quickstart.php to test. The initial quickstart.php code works (Get Calendar Events), so I know I'm able to connect.

However, when I try to use the [events.insert()](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert), it gives me the following error:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: service in /webroot/Website/TestWebsite/root/inc/Calendar/quickstart.php on line 43
```

It's clear that $service isn't defined, but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I installed the Google Client Library using Composer.

Anyone else have this issue?

Below is my code:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/calendar-php-
quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/calendar-php-quickstart.json
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR)
));

$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' => 'Google I/O 2015',
  'location' => '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  'description' => 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer 
products.',
  'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  'recurrence' => array(
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ),
  'attendees' => array(
    array('email' => 'lpage@example.com'),
    array('email' => 'sbrin@example.com'),
  ),
  'reminders' => array(
    'useDefault' => FALSE,
    'overrides' => array(
      array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
      array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
    ),
  ),
));

$calendarId = 'foo_calendar_ID';
$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
printf('Event created: %s\n', $event->htmlLink);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you used the PHP Quickstart, the `$service` variable was working because it was defined in this line

```
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
```

Now, you modified the code and it started giving off errors. Looking at your code, you seemed to have erased that. Now you know what's causing it :)

Comment: @Tim we've all been there : )